# Trouble with scope in Stateless React Component

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm using React Storybook to develop some components. The following accepts the name of the icon and outputs an svg.

```
import React from 'react';
import { string } from 'prop-types';

const Icon = ({ icon }) => {
let resolved = require(`_assets/svg/${icon}.svg`).default;

if (!resolved) {
    throw Error(`Could not find icon ${icon}`);
}

return React.createElement(resolved);

}

Icon.propTypes = {
    icon: string.isRequired
}


export default Icon;
```

This works fine when I call one  component, however if I try and display more than one type of icon they do not appear, or sometimes all appear as the first icon called. I think this is a scope issue, but I can't seem to resolve it.

Comment: I wouldn't play with dynamic `requires`. Why don't you require all of them and keep the references in an object once and simply return the correspondent value when you need a certain key?

Comment: Figured it out - looks like react-svg-loader was converting all of the path ids to the same thing.